# Trigger on insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to create trigger with possibility ROUND value on insert?

This trigger do not work :(

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON repaymentevents
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT round(value, 2) FROM Inserted 
END
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: So, you want your trigger to do a `SELECT` and nothing else?, why would you do that?

Comment: What do you want to do with the value you are selecting?

Comment: Lamak, i want insert data but after round

Comment: on repaymentevents table

Comment: But then, you want the value already inserted **and** the rounded one?

Comment: Well, the `AFTER INSERT` trigger is fired **after** the `INSERT` has happened - you cannot change the data being inserted anymore - it's already inserted. You'll need to look at the `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger - that's where you can tweak your value *before* the insertion happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @marc_s said, I think that you need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON repaymentevents
   INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO repaymentevents
    SELECT round(SomeValue, 2) FROM Inserted 
END
```

[Here is an example.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d29d/4)

Comment: Thank you very much, but why in sql (1 row(s) affected) show 2 time? On sql only 1 record.

Comment: @Fara - What do you mean?, when does that happens?

Comment: After created trigger, i test it. When i insert record to table with script on sql management studio show messages "(1 row(s) affected)" 2 time, but on sql inserted 1 time. Sorry for my English.

Comment: @Fara - `1 row(s) affected` doesn't mean that one row got inserted. Most likely SQL Server is just reporting that there was one record "catched" by the trigger and then one row inserted on the table

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?  This is air-code, obviously I cannot test as I don't have your tables, but hopefully you get the idea.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test
   ON repaymentevents
   AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE repaymentevents 
     INNER
      JOIN INSERTED I
        ON I.id = repaymentevents.id
       SET value = round(i.value, 2)
END
```